# How can I update state asynchronously without action within component?

Tags: reactjs, async-await

As a beginner with React, I'm trying to update my Component State after an async function call.
I have three files : Dashboard.js and GetInfos.

GetInfos is here to execute my fetch, Dashboard is processing my data and sending it to ComponentC which is here to display information.
My first issue is that I don't understand how I can modify my state with the async value that I'm able to log from my **getValue** function.
And I'm not sure that I'm having the right "architecture" in my project, not sure at all if this is the right way to do things.

Any help/advice is welcome.
Below, my actual code

GetInfos has a function that return a fetched value :

```
export async function RetrieveInfos(){
  const dataJobs = await retrieveDataJobs(url,id)

  return dataJobs;
  }
```

And a simplified version of my Dashboard is :

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataJobs: 0
    }

  }

componentDidMount(){
    let myDataJobs;

    async function getValue(){
        myDataJobs = await RetrieveInfos();
        
        //here I can log my async value
        return myDataJobs    
      }
      
    // here I can use this.setState to modify my State, but not with my async value..
 }
    
 render(){
    return 
    <Col>
        <ComponentC label="Data Jobs"
          value={this.state.dataJobs}
        />
    </Col>    
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the `getValue` function is for; you can call `RetrieveInfos` in `cDM` and update the state there. Here you don't call `getValue`, if for some reason `getValue` is important you can update the state in it.

Comment: FYI, "info" is a non-quantitative word (mass noun). Therefore, "infos" is nonstandard. See https://www.grammar-monster.com/plurals/plural_of_information.htm. I'd go with `getInfo`.

Comment: @Davenewton The function getValue is just something I have tried to retrieve the value in an async way, as I wasn't able to call an async function directly inside the CDM (at my knowledge, as CDM isn't async)

Comment: And what prevents calling “setState” inside “getValue”?

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton with your question I understand where I had to search, I'll post my solution

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that async function **GetValue** wasn't having the "this.setState" context correctly.

I change the **componentDidMount** and my function is automatically executed :

```
componentDidMount(){
      
      (async () => {
        let myDataJobs
        myDataJobs = await RetrieveInfo();
        
        this.setState({dataJobs:myDataJobs})  
           
      })();
    
    };
```

Thank you for your help !